# hive queries with jdbc spark sql

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I have java application which runs multiple hive queries using jdbc connection.
Will i be able to run the same queries just on spark sql connected with jdbc without using/having hive.
The queries i have now are like creating tables, doing simple aggregations and joins no major transformations happening . I don't have any UDF's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Spark sql can be handle all the queires which you prepared in hive and there is no need to hive connection.